# Combine Json Array Value to ListView Android

Tags: android, json, listview

Newbie in Android here, with json array like this :

```
[{"SITE_NAME":"JAKARTA","GROUP_LABEL":"FINANCE","COMPANY_ID":"DDT","COMPANY_NAME":"PT. DIADYANI TIMBER","LABEL":"Expenses Req. (EXP) / Pembayaran","TOTAL":1,"SITE_ID":"JKT"},

{"SITE_NAME":"JAKARTA","GROUP_LABEL":"FINANCE","COMPANY_ID":"SPT","COMPANY_NAME":"PT. SARMIENTO PARAKANTJA TIMBER","LABEL":"Expenses Req. (EXP) / Pembayaran","TOTAL":3,"SITE_ID":"JKT"},

{"SITE_NAME":"JAKARTA","GROUP_LABEL":"FINANCE","COMPANY_ID":"TBP","COMPANY_NAME":"PT. TELAGA BAKTI PERSADA","LABEL":"Expenses Req. (EXP) / Pembayaran","TOTAL":1,"SITE_ID":"JKT"},

{"SITE_NAME":"JAKARTA","GROUP_LABEL":"FINANCE","COMPANY_ID":"SPT","COMPANY_NAME":"PT. SARMIENTO PARAKANTJA TIMBER","LABEL":"Payment Req(AP/PO)/Rencana Pembayaran","TOTAL":1,"SITE_ID":"JKT"}]
```

I parse them in my Layout, ListView like this:

- image link : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty23G.png)

See row number 2 and 4, 
There are same name `COMPANY_NAME` with different LABEL

What I want to ask, can I join them so the result will be like this:

PT.SARMIENTO PARAKANTJA TIMBER 
Expenses Req. (EXP) / Pembayaran - JKT (3) 
Payment Req(AP/PO)/Rencana Pembayaran - JKT(1)

Then there will be 3 rows, not 4 with same COMPANY_NAME in ListView.

What must I do? Newbie needs advice. 
Updated :

this is HomeDataList.class

```
public class HomeDataList {

    public String COMPANY_NAME;
    public String TOTAL;
    public String SITE_ID;
    public String LABEL;

    public HomeDataList(String COMPANY_NAME, String LABEL, String SITE_ID,  String TOTAL)
    {
        this.COMPANY_NAME = COMPANY_NAME;
        this.TOTAL = TOTAL;
        this.LABEL = LABEL;
        this.SITE_ID = SITE_ID;
    }

}
```

This is my parsing code :

```
 try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject mJsonObjectProperty = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String COMPANY_NAME = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("COMPANY_NAME");
                String TOTAL = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("TOTAL");
                String SITE_ID = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("SITE_ID");
                String LABEL = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("LABEL");
                listItem.add(new HomeDataList(COMPANY_NAME, LABEL, SITE_ID, TOTAL));
            }
            homeDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("APP", "exception", e);
        }
```

Comment: yes you can do that put you parsing code here

Comment: @AbhishekSingh done, i updated it in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use HashMap here first.

**step 1**

Use Company Name as key

**step 2**

Iterate through each record and if the key with companyname is exist than append value for the object of that key. else add new member to hashmap with comapnyname as key.

**step 3**

Now you have the data for each companyname uniquely

**Step 4**
You can have now arraylist of models in manner you want

This may have more number of looping but you need to traverse through number of loops in order to merge-up the data.

Hope it will work for you.